# Typed map-like structure

Tags: typescript

I'm new to Typescript and I'm basically trying to create a typed map structure where the values should be tied to the keys. This is best explained in some psuedo JS code with no types:

```
const propertyA = "PropertyA";
const propertyB = "PropertyB";

const item1 = "item1";
const item2 = "item2";
const item3 = "item3";
const item4 = "item4";

const arrayA = [item1, item2]; // Should only be used by propertyA
const arrayB = [item1, item3, item4]; // Should only be used by propertyB

{
    PropertyA: arrayA, 
    PropertyB: arrayB,
    ...
}
```

It's a bit contrived, but in a nutshell, I would like to be able to prevent `PropertyB` from being assigned `arrayB`, so this should not be possible:

```
{
    PropertyA: arrayB, 
    PropertyB: arrayA,
    ...
}
```

Being new to Typescript, I had a look around and came across a few examples of `Record` and thought it would also work for me by making a `union` of Records like below:

```
// Typings
type PropertyA = "PropertyA";
type PropertyB = "PropertyB";
type PropertyC = "PropertyC";

type PropertyTypes = PropertyA | PropertyB | PropertyC;

type PropertyAItems = "A" | "B" | "C";
type PropertyBItems = "C" | "D";
type PropertyCItems = "C" | "F";

type PropertyMap =
  | Record<PropertyA, Array<PropertyAItems>>
  | Record<PropertyB, Array<PropertyBItems>>
  | Record<PropertyC, Array<PropertyCItems>>;

// The implementation

const testMap: PropertyMap = {
  PropertyA: ["A", "B", "C"],
  PropertyB: ["C", "D"],
  PropertyC: ["C", "F"]
};
```

I expect to be able to do something like `testMap.PropertyA` and get back `["A", "B", "C"]`, but instead I get the following error:

```
Property 'PropertyA' does not exist on type 'PropertyMap'.
Property 'PropertyA' does not exist on type 'Record<"PropertyB", PropertyBItems[]>'
```

So... I'm obviously doing something wrong somewhere, so I'd be grateful for any help, but more importantly, is this even the right approach to take? I would love to hear any other suggestions. Like I said, I'm new to Typescript, so it's a whole new world.

Comment: So, are you looking for tuples? A signature like `PropertyA: [string, string]`, for example will prevent `["a", "b", "c"]` from being assigned there.

Comment: Hmmm in that case, if I understand it correctly, the consumer would be able to use the wrong arrays for PropertyB and PropertyC seeing as both would be `[string, string]`. I want to values available to each property to be finite, i.e., `PropertyB` can only have an array of `PropertyBItems` assigned to it.

Comment: Well, that just means that you want `PropertyB: PropertyBItems[]`  or `PropertyB: [PropertyBItem, PropertyBItem]` depending on whether you want any number or a tuple.

Comment: Your `PropertyMap` should probably be using [intersections](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) (`&`) instead of [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) (`|`) but `Record<"a", string> & Record<"b", number>` is a roundabout way of saying `{a: string, b: number}` so @georg's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58150977/2887218) is in the right direction.   "Typed maps where the values are tied to the keys" are what [interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) are for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler way to describe that interface would be

```
interface PropertyMap { 
  PropertyA: Array<"A" | "B" | "C">
  PropertyB: Array<"C" | "D">
  PropertyC: Array<"C" | "F">
}
```

and then, for example,

```
const testMap: PropertyMap = {
  PropertyA: ["A", "B", "B", "B"],
  PropertyB: ["C", "D", "D", "D", "D"],
  PropertyC: ["C", "F", "C", "F"]
};
```

Provided you actually want the values to be arrays and not tuples.

Comment: This was the approach I took in the end. Thanks for all the help and suggestions guys!